# How can I search for a file within a directory and its sub-directories in c?

Tags: c, linux, file, find

How can I search for a file  within a directory and its sub-directories in C? 
I'm not allowed to use `find`  and I must use `opendir` , `readdir` and `stat`.

I want to perform something like the command `ls -ln` if the file indeed exists.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That should be in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For traversing the directories, you will need: [opendir(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/opendir.html), [readdir(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/readdir.html), and [closedir(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/closedir.html).

For checking the type of file (to see if it's a directory and if you should recursively search within it) you will need [stat(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/stat.html).

You will want to check

```
(struct stat).st_mode & S_IFDIR
```

to see if the file is a directory. See [<sys/stat.h>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If we try to write a small piece of code in C then we can do this search activity easily.
Suppose you need to search abc.txt in a /home/Jack/  then just open a file stream and pass the file path as a parameter.
Now when this statement will be executed, it will try to open the existing file. This API will return non zero if the file exists otherwise it is returned -1 or zero.

Answer (score 0):

You've already provided the basic answer: `opendir`/`readdir`/`closedir`. As you walk the directory entries, you check whether each refers to a file or a directory. Those that refer to directories, you traverse as well (typically recursively). For those that refer to files, you compare their names to the file(s) you're looking for, and see if you've found it.

One other minor detail: you probably also want to check for symbolic links. A symbolic link can (for example) refer to a parent directory, which could/can lead to infinite recursion. You may want to ignore symbolic links completely, or you may want to keep a list of directories you've already at least started to traverse, and resolve/traverse what's in the symbolic link only if it's not already in the list.